# How to find power required for rotating blades given the required shear cutting force

Tags: torque, power, design

I want to design a sugar cane bud cutting machine. The rotating blades are connected to the output shaft of a speed reduction box ($30\,{\rm rpm}$). The shear force required for cutting is $1200\,{\rm N}$. How should I choose the diameter of the blade and the motor power?

Answer (score 1):

Motor power  determines a maximum to the rate of cutting, because the size of
a bud (distance of blade travel in a cut) times 1200N is an energy requirement to complete
a single cut.   This limit applies regardless of speed and gearing and cutter
radius. $$P_{motor} >= N_{cuts/second} \times X_{cut} \times 1200N $$

If the rotating mass of the motor is significant (it is a flywheel), it can
cut with very low average torque (just as a long swing of the arm can
drive an axe into a log with more force than if you just set the edge
against the wood and pushed).   So, it is hard to know the force (torque)
requirement at the motor, but the reduction gears will have to
supply a torque equal or greater than $$T_{gearbox} = 1200N \times R_{blade}$$
while cutting a single bud.  The motor shaft torque will be one thirtieth of the
gearbox output torque, of course.   Motor power is an upper limit on
motor torque times motor rotation rate, but it is rare that one wishes to
operate a motor near that limit.
$$P_{motor} >= T_{gearbox}  \times \omega (rpm) \times 120 \pi/30$$

No exact solution here, just limits to what is possible.